# How can I change xlink:href for all <image> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's assume I cannot modify an HTML source code, however I do know, that all image tags look like:

```
<image id="shadows" xlink:href="https://...pic.png"></image>
<image id="lights" xlink:href="https://...pic.png"></image>
<image id="views" xlink:href="https://...pic.png"></image>
...
```

I don't like the image - "https://...pic.png", I wish to use instead locally installed image - "./beautiful.png"

How can I replace xlink:href attiribute for ALL image tags (I can still modify js/css)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementById` to find each element by their id and replace their `xlink:href` attribute with Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/8cz46vt2/

For example:

```
document.getElementById("shadows").setAttribute("xlink:href", "./beautiful.png");
```

will yield:

```
<image id="shadows" xlink:href="./beautiful.png"></image>
```

Comment: thank you for your time! Yes this way you CAN, indeed, modify the image tag attributes, however, it is such a headache to hardcode all them by id

Comment: Have you tried this approach with querySelectorAll? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/  If the xlink:href are the same, you may use it as the selector (a bad practice ofc, but I don't know your exact requirements), go through the element and set the xlink:href attribute to `beautiful.png`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

```js
function updateImageTag() {
  // Get all image tags
  const imageTags = document.querySelectorAll("image");

  // Loop through all image tags
  imageTags.forEach((imageTag) => {
    // Get the xlink:href attribute of the image tag
    const xlinkHref = imageTag.getAttribute("xlink:href");

    // If the xlink:href attribute is "https://...pic.png"
    if (xlinkHref === "https://...pic.png") {
      // Update the xlink:href attribute to be "./beautiful.png"
      imageTag.setAttribute("xlink:href", "./beautiful.png");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changePic() {
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('image')
    for (let i in elements) { 
        elements[i].setAttribute("xlink:href", "./beautiful.png")
    }
}
```

Then call the changePic() function wherever you want to :)

Comment: thank you for your time, unfortunately doesn't work:
Uncaught TypeError: elements[i].setAttribute is not a function

Comment: @Azii You're right. But works fine using "img" tag instead of "image".

Example: `<img id="shadows" xlink:href="https://...pic.png"/>`